# Laravel - How to use access token without filling it inside the postman?

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I have created an API in Laravel using Passport, everything is working fine, generating the access token and using the token in Postman to show the data. When the user is login, I save the access token in the database Users table The problem is that I have to pass the access token in the header part of postman manually. How I can pass the generated access token automatically to the header, or anywhere, there I need.

Answer (score 2):

There is no choice, you have to add the token to the header in every request. To make things easy, you can create a 'Collection' in postman and set, for that collection, the login token. It will remain there in every request of the project.
[image: Postman working]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: yes sure, and if you don't mind, please upvote my question :)